# story identification: A cowboy with a robotic horse sees a wisp of smoke

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic, soft-sci-fi

The story takes place in the post-apocalyptic Earth. The wild life has become extremely dangerous. A cowboy is in the clean room where he keeps the cows (maybe during the night) and sees a fly on the wall which shouldn't be there. On the next day he sees a wisp of smoke coming from an area that is presumed uninhabited. He goes to investigate on his robotic horse. Somehow his horse was damaged near the place where the smoke was seen. He had to return to his farm on foot (extremely dangerous) but his return path crosses an abandoned highway. In the middle of the highway there is another robotic horse without a master and standing there for years, presumably damaged or with dead battery. But as the hero approaches the horse wakes up and offers him help.

*This may be part of a bigger text but I am not sure.*

Edit - more details: I've read this story about 1994-1996. It was say 20 pages. It is possible that this was a part of longer text because at that time we had no IP laws and everybody was printing everything. It was published in Bulgarian in a small book (half size paperback 50-60 pages) with several other stories. I have a very dim memory that the author's name sounded Japanese but I am almost sure that it was translated from English.

Thank you community.

Comment: This is a good start, but you might be able to get an answer faster if you add a few more details. Our guide at https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/ might help.

Comment: You can answer your own question below if you wish.

Comment: I'd phrase it more strongly than Tim did: please remove the answer from your question and post it as a, well, *answer* instead.

Comment: Yes, what Martha said. This is Question and Answers site: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour It's fine if you answer your own question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Yes please do add an answer! Preferably with some extra details about the story. :)

Comment: It is more than recommended that you answer your own question: you *should not* put the answer in the text of the question, ans it is *accepting an answer* that marks a question as successfully handled. (Alas, you'll have to wait a bit to accept a self-answer.)

Answer (score 2):

For the benefit of future seekers, per an edit by the OP that has since been reversed: "The story is Bulgarian, it is 'One Thin Wisp of Smoke' by Krasnomir Krachunov."